# How to change Selection colour(AM,PM) and time of GraphicalDatePickerStyle Date picker Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, uidatepicker

How to Change `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` Date picker text color and Selection Colour:-

**Code:-**

```
 DatePicker("Time",selection: dateProxy,displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    .accentColor(.white)
    .labelsHidden()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

But I want to achieve `DatePicker` given below, is it possible in `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` Style or not?

Try to Achieve:-

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the dark mode picker! Just apply  the `dark` `colorScheme` to the component:

```
DatePicker("Time", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    .background(Color.black)
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) // <- This modifier
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

---

## Apply color

Also, you can apply the `colorMultiply` modifier for coloring the picker in a pleasant way:

[image: Colors]

---

## Demo Full Code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var date = Date()

    var colors: [Color] = [.white, .gray, .red, .green, .blue, .orange, .yellow, .pink, .purple] // <- You can use any color! This is just for demonstrate

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(colors, id:\.self) { color in
                DatePicker("Time", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    .background(Color.black.grayscale(1))
                    .colorMultiply(color) // <- This line does the trick
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) // <- Don't Forget this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for macOS 11 and iOS 14 (Xcode 12 beta 3)...

1.Take the Label out of the DatePicker - I've left it commented out here so its obvious to readers that the Label should be taken out of the DatePicker View.

1. Place the DatePicker in an HStack (or other ViewBuilder.
2. Add a Label for the DatePicker in the HStack.
3. Use the .colorMultiplier view modifier to change the color of the DatePicker date and time "button".

In this particular example I am also changing the colour of the date and time "button" depending on whether the binding value in the date picker is nil.

```
    let now = Date()
        HStack {
            Text("Date")
            DatePicker(selection: Binding($observedObject.date, replacingNilWith: now)) {
//              Text("Date")
//                  .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
            }
            .colorMultiply(observedObject.date == nil ? Color(.placeholderText) : Color(.label))
        }
```

Also I'm using an extension to Binding in this example which is something I use throughout my core data projects.

```
public extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
    init(_ source: Binding<Value?>, replacingNilWith nilProxy: Value) {
        self.init(
            get: { source.wrappedValue ?? nilProxy },
            set: { newValue in
                if newValue == nilProxy {
                    source.wrappedValue = nil
                }
                else {
                    source.wrappedValue = newValue
                }
        })
    }
}
```

As always full credit to **Alan Quatermain** for this extension to Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I got:

```swift
      Group {
         DatePicker("Time",selection: $dateProxy, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            .accentColor(.black)
            .colorInvert()
            .labelsHidden()
            .padding()
      }
      .background(Color.black.opacity(0.8))
```

[image]